# smooth edges of a segmented mask

Tags: python, image, opencv

is it possible to smooth edges using openCV(python). [mask](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iep43.jpg).

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7416025/how-do-i-smooth-the-curvescontours-in-opencv
Is what you are looking for?

Comment: I also found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37068448/opencv-how-to-smooth-contour-reducing-noise

Comment: Thanks Cezar. I wanted to understand the steps that are being used in the link. The answer you provided also can help but it is giving a white image right now.

Comment: Can you provide a sample image?

Comment: I have edited the question.

Answer (score 5):

Try this code:

```
import cv2

print(cv2.__version__)

img = cv2.imread('iep43.jpg', 0)
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (11, 11))
(thresh, binRed) = cv2.threshold(img, 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
opening = cv2.morphologyEx(img, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel, iterations=3)
cv2.imwrite("cleaned.jpg", opening)
```

It uses the morphological operation of opening